# Wifi - wpa_supplicant throwing no such device error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am testing wifi in Ubuntu PC using wpa_supplicant utility. In PC, network device is listed as wlp3s0, when I tried to connect to wifi network using below command
**wpa_supplicant -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp3s0** following error was displaying

**Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3s0 flags: No such device 

nl80211: Could not set interface 'p2p-dev-wlp3s0' UP 

nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0 

p2p-dev-wlp3s0: Failed to initialize driver interface 

P2P: Failed to enable P2P Device interface**

I have below obsevation :

- if we kill background wpa_supplicant service running onboot , run the **wpa_supplicant -B -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlp3s0** command
  one error will come **Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3s0 flags: No such device** but still wifi connects and ping works
- When I checked through wpa_Supplicant(2.6) source, without adding P2P support in configuration file , connection works and ping too [Note : onboot wpa_Supplicant service is not running]
- When I add P2P package support in .config file , same issue . I could see all 5 errors.
  From wpa_Supplicant source came to know that **p2p-dev** gets append with **wlp3s0** to get that interface name **p2p-dev-wlp3s0**

Please let me know ,how to get that p2p-dev-wlp3s0 in ifconfig. How to resolve this error

**Thanks in advance,**

**Regards,
Deeksha**